# How do I open up an element in a new tab?

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/opulentbase/Downloads/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.gooogle.com/')

searchBar = browser.find_element_by_name('q')

userSearch = input("Please enter a search: ")

searchBar.send_keys(userSearch)

searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

morePlaces = browser.find_element_by_class_name('i0vbXd')

morePlaces.click()

locations = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('dbg0pd')

for location in locations:
    location.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    website = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Website')
    website.click()
```

Instead of website.click() which opens the element link in the same window I want to know how I can open the element in a new tab. I've tried looking up a couple of tutorials online but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance, i'm new to coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me while working on instagram, the code below opened new tab:
driver is the same as browser

```
# to get the current window handler for future to return
curwindowhndl = driver.current_window_handle
# open link in new tab keyboard shortcut
driver.execute_script('''window.open("about:blank", "_blank");''')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])  # assuming new tab is at index 1
# edit 1
driver.get(your_search_url)
```

After finishing your work on new tab :

```
driver.close()  # closes new tab
driver.switch_to.window(curwindowhndl)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I put the website element in here: driver.execute_script('''window.open("website"''')

Comment: I personally prefer to make a 
1- url of that page with search token 
2- blank tab and 
3- driver.get(url)
ex: search for "hello world" in google results in a specific url 
send that url to new_window's get method.
please see my edit